# Error in running ASP.Net Web App on ARM processor (Raspberry Pi 3 B) / Ubuntu (Natively without Mono)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, raspberry-pi, .net-core

I followed the guide bellow to run a simple `C#` console program on my ubuntu box, and everything went smoothly. (I am trying to run everything **natively using `.Net Core` without any usage of `Mono`**!)

The guide:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

But when I did the same, trying to run an `ASP.Net web application` (the very basic and simple template generated by Visual Studio), I get this error:

```
root@dotnet:/dotnet/aspnetcore/PublishOutput# /dotnet/dotnet WebApplication1.dll

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.CreateFileWatcher(String root)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.Initialize(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, String applicationName, String contentRootPath, WebHostOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildHostingServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at WebApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could some one help me to **solve that and to run ASP.Net App natively** on my RPi3?

P.S. I don't think this is important, but I am working in `Docker` container.

Comment: There seems to be an issue for this on the [dotnet GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9168)

Comment: @TomKuijsten Ok then I have to wait for a solution from MS. thx

Comment: @TomKuijsten if you are interested, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some one on GitHub found the solution!! big thanks to him. Actually it is a workaround till we can build the app on ARM directly or find another real solution, but this workaround works very good now!

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9168#issuecomment-277846829