# Windows 10 IoT Core host Web API ASP.Net Core. Possible?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Im messing around with my Raspberry Pi 3 and Windows 10 IoT Core.
I would like to host a WebApi (ASP.NET Core) on the Raspberry. 
I cant find any guides.

I've found guides like this: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

But thats only for console apps maybe?

Has anyone tried?
Is it possible?

Your thoughts?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can vote up [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1531).

Comment: You were on the right track! Most service development in C# is done in the context of a console app. I wish I'd seen this post a few years ago, would love to have helped ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your links!
I've stumbled upon a great wiki for this, but not on Windows 10 IoT.
This guy is using Ubuntu on his Raspberry (Ubuntu mate). 
He seems dedicated so I will change OS on my Raspberry and try.

Here's the link: https://github.com/challe/dotnet-core-raspberry-pi/wiki/Setting-up-a-Web-API-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-3-(Ubuntu-16.04)-using-.NET-Core-2.x

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's possible and I have some plan to try.
But for you will be useful to follow Scott Hanselman. He knows a lot about it.
Look at this arcticle:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunASPNET5Beta3OrGoLangOnARaspberryPi2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's some links about the same thing with potential work arounds.  Planning on doing this myself so would be good to know one how you get on.

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1531

[Error in running ASP.Net Web App on ARM processor (Raspberry Pi 3 B) / Ubuntu (Natively without Mono)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054399/error-in-running-asp-net-web-app-on-arm-processor-raspberry-pi-3-b-ubuntu-n)

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9168

Answer (score 0):

> This week a friend of mine pointed out this GitHub page which
>   explained how you could get the dotnet runtime going on a Win10Iot Pi.
>   My first reaction to this post was… can I run ASP.NET Core projects? A
>   few hours later I had it running. It’s quit a hassle to get it going,
>   so I thought it would be a good idea to put it all into one post. Here
>   we go!

More detailed explanations can be read directly from [his site](http://www.devvy.nl/?p=170).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best guide that I've found and been able to use:

http://www.devvy.nl/?p=170

Comment: Your link was already mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Step by step: Running ASP.NET Core on Raspberry Pi"   https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/21/step-by-step-running-aspnet-core-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: If you are looking for a sample which uses latest ASP.NET Core 2.0 release and also toggles gpios on you RPi check: https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/09/01/toggle-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-with-asp-net-core-20/

There is no longer need of adding a reference to libuv.

Comment: Nope it's for Raspbian but you can publish the sample with the following command:  dotnet publish -r win-arm and then copy the files to Windows IoT. (Not sure if the gpio lib will work)

Comment: Just answer th question regarding startup... Hope it helps!